# Prevent rsync out of memory

Tags: linux, memory, android, rsync

I am trying to `rsync` 55000 jpg files in 10000 folders (from an Android phone to a Linux box). Usually, I did this:

```
rsync -rOi --size-only --delete --timeout=60 --progress --no-perms --rsync-path="/system/bin/rsync" remoteBox/foo/bar/Songs/ LocalSongsDir
```

However, since my last Android system """""upgrade""""" (CYM11), I get zillions of "Out of memory" errors from rsync:

```
rsync: readlink_stat("/foo/bar/file") failed: Out of memory (12)
```

I know this is due to the amount of files, and I know I could do a per-directory rsync to avoid the OOM. But I have 10000 folders, and that would take forever.

I read the manual, and the suggestions there did not solve the OOM.

Any clues on how I can tweak the command line options to solve the OOM? What I tried didn't work...

Thanks!

L.

Comment: What about `find` and a `for` loop to target each directory?

Comment: @unkilbeeg: 10000 folders... Moreover, I also have memory problems even listing ONE file! See here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84330/ls-filename-cannot-allocate-memory

Comment: You could maybe try nested for loops to handle the huge number of folders. I've tried tricks like that in the past. But if listing *one* file causes memory problems, that sounds like a *different* issue than the number of folders, and may have to be solved before rsync can work.

Comment: Exactly. It seems a problem with the OS.

Comment: See if it works better if you leave out ``-i``. I could imagine that this is expensive over many files.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: The problem goes far beyond `rsync`. Sometimes even listing ONE file in the extSDCard I got `cannot allocate memory`. This was also fixed by the reformatting of the card to ext4.

Answer (score 0):

Cyanogenmod 11 is extremely buggy on the Galaxy Note I (N7000), and this seems to be one more of its bugs. I solved it by reformatting the card to `ext4` (reformatting to `exfat` didn't solve the problem.